# Wouldn't each thread require its own copy of the JVM?

Tags: java, multithreading, process, jvm

I'm trying to figure out how the JVM works with regard to spawning multiple threads. I think my mental model may be a little off, but right now I am stuck on grokking this idea: since there is only one copy of the JVM running at any time, wouldn't each thread require its own copy of the JVM? I realize that the multiple threads of a java application are mapped to native os threads, but I don't get how the threads that are not running the JVM are crunching bytecode; is it that all threads somehow have access to the JVM? thanks, any help appreciated.

Comment: afaik: threads = all in same JVM instance, Processes different instances - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html or http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html#concurrency_processthreads

Comment: *"since there is only one copy of the JVM running at any time"* --> where did you get that from? it is not true in general.

Comment: @BrunoReis I meant only one JVM per process, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit oversimplified and some of what I wrote isn't strictly correct, but the essence is this:

> since there is only one copy of the JVM running at any time, wouldn't each thread require its own copy of the JVM?

Not really. You could permit multiple threads to read from one piece of memory (as in same address in memory) and thus have only one JVM. However, you need to be careful so that threads don't create a mess when they access such shared resources (JVM) concurrently, as it is the case in the real world (imagine two people trying to type two different documents at the same time with one PC).

One strategy of having multiple threads working okay together with some shared resource (such as JVM (stack, heap, byte code compiler), console, printer etc.) is indeed having copies for each threads (one PC for each person). For example, each threads has its own stack.

This is however not the only way. For example, immutable resources (like class byte codes in memory) can be shared among multiple threads without problem through shared memory. If a piece of memo doesn't change, two people can both safely look at that memo at the same time. Similarly, because class byte code doesn't change, multiple threads can read them at the same time from one copy.

Another way is to use a lock to sort things out between the threads (whoever is touching the mouse get's to use the PC). For example, you could imagine a JVM in which there is only one byte code interpreter which is shared among all threads and is protected by one global lock (which would be very inefficient in practice, but you get the idea).

There are also some other advanced mechanism to let multiple threads work with shared resources. People who developed the JVM used these techniques and that's why you don't need a copy of JVM per thread.

Answer (score 5):

> but I don't get how the threads that are not running the JVM are crunching bytecode; is it that all threads somehow have access to the JVM?

http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/jvmP.html explains this well. Here is what it says:

"**Each thread of a running Java application is a distinct instance of the virtual machine's execution engine.** From the beginning of its lifetime to the end, a thread is either executing bytecodes or native methods. A thread may execute bytecodes directly, by interpreting or executing natively in silicon, or indirectly, by just- in-time compiling and executing the resulting native code. A Java virtual machine implementation may use other threads invisible to the running application, such as a thread that performs garbage collection. Such threads need not be "instances" of the implementation's execution engine. All threads that belong to the running application, however, are execution engines in action."

Summarizing my understanding of this:

For every thread (execpt GC thread and ilk),  corresponding ExecutionEngine instance (in the same JVM) converts bytecodes to machine instructions and native OS thread executes those machine instructions. Of course, I am **not** talking about green thread here.

Comment: Nice, so that means JVM will have multi execution engine instance running at the same time

Comment: Yes, except threads like GC thread which doesn't do any Bytecode crunching.

Answer (score 2):

By definitions threads in a Java application share the same memory space, therefore are executing within the same JVM. This way you can easily share objects across multiple threads, perform synchronization and such, all that is happening within the JVM.

One way to see it is that processes have their own memory space, while threads within an application share the same memory space.